# how to edit the alert success submission in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, web, submission

Hi I am editing a website, there is the form submission there, where I use formspree to submit forms (names, email, comments). then click the **send** button.

Everything works well, expect the successful alert looks weird... see picture below:

[image]

[image]

I am trying to edit this, but couldn't figure out how. I want it to show *"Thanks, your submission is successful!"*.

I found the javascript code for this part:

```
// Form Validation !Plugin @v1.0
    NioApp.Plugins.submitform = function () {
        var $form = $('.nk-form-submit');
        
        if( !$().validate && !$().ajaxSubmit ) {
            console.log('jQuery Form and Form Validate not Defined.');
            return true;
        }
        
        if ($form.exists()) {
            $form.each(function(){
                var $self = $(this), _result = $self.find('.form-results');
                $self.validate({
                    ignore: [],
                    invalidHandler: function () { _result.slideUp(400); },
                    submitHandler: function(form) {
                    _result.slideUp(400);
                    $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                        target: _result, dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(data) {
                            var type = (data.result==='error') ? 'alert-danger' : 'alert-success';
                            _result.removeClass( 'alert-danger alert-success' ).addClass( 'alert ' + type ).html(data.message).slideDown(400);
                            if (data.result !== 'error') { $(form).clearForm().find('input').removeClass('input-focused'); }
                        }
                    });
                    }
                });
                $self.find('.select').on('change', function() { $(this).valid(); });
            });
        }
    };
    NioApp.components.docReady.push(NioApp.Plugins.submitform);
```

and the code in css:

```
.alert-success { color: #29cf77; background: #cef5e1; }

.alert-success .close { background: #64e09e; }

.alert-success-alt { background: #39d884; }

.alert-success-alt .close { background: #25b96b; }
```

can anyone give me some hints how to change it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will take a part of the javascript in the question to focus

```
                    $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                        target: _result, dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(data) {
                            var type = (data.result==='error') ? 'alert-danger' : 'alert-success';
                            _result.removeClass( 'alert-danger alert-success' ).addClass( 'alert ' + type ).html(data.message).slideDown(400);
                            if (data.result !== 'error') { $(form).clearForm().find('input').removeClass('input-focused'); }
                        }
                    });
```

This part is the `ajax` part, which is responsible to submit the data after validation, the return after successful submission is stored in the object `data` which has two attributes. `data.result` gives the submission status, and `data.message` carry the message to be displayed in a `div`. this `div` which has a class name `.form-results`, which is pointed by the object `_result` ( `_result = $self.find('.form-results')`)

The line below changes the class of the div according to `data.status` and display the message sent after submition

```
                            _result.removeClass( 'alert-danger alert-success' ).addClass( 'alert ' + type ).html(data.message).slideDown(400);
```

Therefore, either the message to be sent after submission or make a short modification for the case of success or failure.

if we go to make this modification, so just before mentioned line above we add:

```
if (data.result !== 'error') {data.message="Thanks, your submission is successful!";}
else { data.message = "Submition failed";}
```

so the code becomes

```
                    $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                        target: _result, dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(data) {
                            var type = (data.result==='error') ? 'alert-danger' : 'alert-success';
                             /////////////////////////////////////////////
                             if (data.result !== 'error') {data.message="Thanks, your submission is successful!";}
                             else { data.message = "Submition failed";}
                             //////////////////////////////////////////////
                            _result.removeClass( 'alert-danger alert-success' ).addClass( 'alert ' + type ).html(data.message).slideDown(400);
                            if (data.result !== 'error') { $(form).clearForm().find('input').removeClass('input-focused'); }
                        }
                    });
```

as clear now it is not important to get the solution but also so important to understand the code.

Comment: Thanks Nour-Allah. Your explanation is very clear and easy to understand. I am not familiar with JS, but after your explanation I am kinda know how it works now. 


I tested it out, it works, but I have some other display issue. I believe it's the CSS... I tried to delete the css alert or alert-success, also tried to look for the form-results class, and change the color... but the white box is always pop up when I submit the form.... do you know where I can change it? 

weird things is in my safari browser I don't even see the text, but my phone, at least I see the text with the white box

Comment: if you put all HTML file on  https://codepen.io/trending   and send the link, I will see the whole figure and would discuss more clearly.

Comment: Since the topic of your question is solved, it is better to accept the answer and open another question with the other issues, but do not forget to put your full HTML, CSS, and Js on https://codepen.io/trending  and put the link in both the new question as well as in the comments under my answer, so I can follow you.